# How to loop through JSON array?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I have some JSON-code which has multiple objects in it:

```
[
    {
        "MNGR_NAME": "Mark",
        "MGR_ID": "M44",
        "EMP_ID": "1849"
    },
    {
        "MNGR_NAME": "Steve",
        "PROJ_ID": "88421",
        "PROJ_NAME": "ABC",
        "PROJ_ALLOC_NO": "49"
    }
]
```

My JSON loop snippet is:

```
function ServiceSucceeded(result) 
{       
  for(var x=0; x<result.length; x++) 
  {      

  }    
}
```

Could you please let me know how to check there is no occurence of "MNGR_NAME" in the array. (It appears twice in my case.)

Comment: does 'no' in your question mean 'number'?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to access the `result` object on iteration.

```
for (var key in result)
{
   if (result.hasOwnProperty(key))
   {
      // here you have access to
      var MNGR_NAME = result[key].MNGR_NAME;
      var MGR_ID = result[key].MGR_ID;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped my JSON array rid itself from bad data. But why is that data getting sent through? How come you have to check that extra if?

Comment: Thank you for using straight JavaScript.

Answer (score 7):

You could use jQuery's [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
    var exists = false;

    $.each(arr, function(index, obj){
       if(typeof(obj.MNGR_NAME) !== 'undefined'){
          exists = true;
          return false;
       }
    });

    alert('Does a manager exists? ' + exists);
```

Returning `false` will break the each, so when one manager is encountered, the iteration will stop.

Comment: If you want to count, you should not return `false`, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your object is an array of JavaScript objects.
Could you use something like this?

```
var array = [{
    "MNGR_NAME": "Mark",
    "MGR_ID": "M44",
    "EMP_ID": "1849"
},
{
    "MNGR_NAME": "Steve",
    "PROJ_ID": "88421",
    "PROJ_NAME": "ABC",
    "PROJ_ALLOC_NO": "49"
}];

var numberOfMngrName = 0;
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(array[i].MNGR_NAME != null){
        numberOfMngrName++;
    }
}

console.log(numberOfMngrName);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will find the number of occurrences of the `MNGR_NAME` key in your `Object` `Array`:

```
var numMngrName = 0;

$.each(json, function () {
    // 'this' is the Object you are iterating over
    if (this.MNGR_NAME !== undefined) {
        numMngrName++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the loop `result[x]` is the object, so if you wanted to count a member that may or may not be present;

```
function ServiceSucceeded(result)
{
  var managers = 0
  for(var x=0; x<result.length; x++)
  {
        if (typeof result[x].MNGR_NAME !== "undefined")
            managers++;
  }
  alert(managers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use $.each or $.grep, if you also want to get the elements that contain the attribute.

```
filtered = $.grep(result, function(value) {
    return (value["MNGR_NAME"] !== undefined)
});
count = filtered.length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the collection and check each object if it contains the property:

```
var count = 0;
var i;
for(i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i += 1) {
    if(jsonObj[i]["MNGR_NAME"]) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/j3fbQ/

Answer (score 0):

Use ES6...

```
myobj1.map(items =>
{
if(items.MNGR_NAME) {
return items.MNGR_NAME;
}else {
//do want you want.
}    
})
```

Thanks.