# Looping through json object without child name

Tags: android, json

I want to retrieve the values of all element in this json format document.

```
[
            {
                "id": "c0001xgp",
                "title": 8.8,
                "content": 142.369,
                "vignette": "us",
                "image": "2011-03-11 04:46:23",
                "type": 24.4,
                "pubdate": 38.322
          },
            {
                "id": "c0001xgp",
                "title": 8.8,
                "content": 142.369,
                "vignette": "us",
                "image": "2011-03-11 04:46:23",
                "type": 24.4,
                "pubdate": 38.322
          },  {
                "id": "c0001xgp",
                "title": 8.8,
                "content": 142.369,
                "vignette": "us",
                "image": "2011-03-11 04:46:23",
                "type": 24.4,
                "pubdate": 38.322
          },  {
                "id": "c0001xgp",
                "title": 8.8,
                "content": 142.369,
                "vignette": "us",
                "image": "2011-03-11 04:46:23",
                "type": 24.4,
                "pubdate": 38.322
          }
```

]

how can i achieve this. i'm learning json and android. when there is a parent in the json object i can deal with but now i am have trouble to solve this problem.

The main class

```
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_ARRAY= "";

private static final String TAG_ID = "id";

private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";

private static final String TAG_CONTENT = "content";

private static final String TAG_VIGNETTE = "vignette";

private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";

private static final String TAG_TYPE = "type";

private static final String TAG_PUBDATE = "pubdate";


// contacts JSONArray

JSONArray myArray = null;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.actus);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
     JSONArray jArray = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);


        // looping through All element
        for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){


            JSONObject oneObject = null;
            try{

            oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id;

            String title;

                title = oneObject.getString(TAG_TITLE);


            String content = oneObject.getString(TAG_CONTENT);

            String vignette = oneObject.getString(TAG_VIGNETTE);

            String image = oneObject.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

            String type = oneObject.getString(TAG_TYPE);

            String pubdate = oneObject.getString(TAG_PUBDATE);


            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

            map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);

            map.put(TAG_CONTENT, content);

            map.put(TAG_VIGNETTE, vignette);

            map.put(TAG_TYPE, type);

            map.put(TAG_PUBDATE, pubdate);



            // adding HashList to ArrayList

            contactList.add(map);


            }catch (JSONException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch
```

block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

```
        }



    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_CONTENT, TAG_VIGNETTE }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();

            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();

            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_VIGNETTE, name);

            in.putExtra(TAG_CONTENT, cost);

            in.putExtra(TAG_VIGNETTE, description);

            startActivity(in);

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: can you post the whole JSON what are you getting ? Is something missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

parse current json String as to get all values from json Object :

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray("your json String");

for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
{
  JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
   // get all value here
   String str_eqid=oneObject.getString("eqid");
   String str_magnitude=oneObject.getString("magnitude");
   String str_lng=oneObject.getString("lng");
   String str_src=oneObject.getString("src");

    // get other values from jsonobject in same way
}
```

and use `ArrayList` and `HashMap` for Storing  values

Comment: please what is this "your json string" ? is it the url

Comment: @sophia : "your json String" means what result you are getting from server

Comment: the json start with "[{" only on the server. that's where my trouble is

Comment: @sophia : plz httpget or hhtppost  code where you  are retrieving string from server

Comment: i am following this example: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: see this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489288/how-to-loop-through-json-array its similar

Comment: just want the looping part

Comment: @sophia : if you are using http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ example then change your Activity as http://pastebin.com/sMCVpYV5 and JSONParser as http://pastebin.com/2Hidht6D

Comment: i have updated the question with your solution and using your jsonparser http://pastebin.com/2Hidht6D but the screen remain blank

Comment: @sophia : everything fine in your code i think just check contactList, HashMap size and value using log

Comment: @sophia : oh!! i mean plz put log inside activity and let me known you are getting value in ArrayList or not

Comment: i did it dude but it does not go in try block instead its directed to the catch exception error. i guess it is not stream

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23211/discussion-between--k-and-sophia)

Answer (score 4):

"As you said there is no parent so you have to use JSONArray through which you need to looping and get all JSON Objects."

```
 try
  {  JSONArray mp3 = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
     JSONObject c = new JSONObject();                          

                    // looping through All 
                    for (int i = 0; i < mp3.length(); i++) 
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            c = mp3.getJSONObject(i);

                            String id = c.getString(TAG_mp3_id); 
                            String title = c.getString(TAG_title);


                            // tmp hashmap for single contact
                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String,String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            contact.put(TAG_mp3_id, id);
                            contact.put(TAG_title, title);


                            // adding contact to contact list
                            mp3List.add(contact);


                        }    
                        catch (JSONException e) 
                        {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
```

"Hope this will help you."

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(YourString);
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("eqid"));
}
```