# Parsing JSON objects for HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I am trying to display a "leaderboard" table based on JSON data.

I have read a lot about the JSON format and overcome some initial obstacles, but my Javascript knowledge is very limited and I need help!

Basically my JSON data comes through looking like this:

```
[{"User_Name":"John Doe","score":"10","team":"1"},{"User_Name":"Jane Smith","score":"15","team":"2"},{"User_Name":"Chuck Berry","score":"12","team":"2"}]
```

What I need is to be able to loop through this array, generating a table row or list item for each object. There will be an unknown amount of total objects in the array but each will have the same format- three values: Name, Score, Team.

So far I have used the following code, which confirms that I am successfully loading the objects in the console-

```
$.getJSON(url,
function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

but I am not sure how to iterate over them, parsing them into the HTML table.

The next step is sorting the entries by score in descending order...

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

EDIT:

Updated code below, this works:

```
$.getJSON(url,
function (data) {
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].User_Name + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].score + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].team + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);
    }
});
```

(The $.parseJSON was not necessary, we can use 'data' as the JSON array is already parsed I believe)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @roasted: Well, yes. That's what OP stated in the question. It's JSON that's being parsed into an Array.

Comment: @CrazyTrain  oops forget this part thx

Comment: Please see the following posts:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078118/how-to-iterate-over-a-json-structure

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489288/how-to-loop-through-json-array

Comment: bad example: script injection vuln.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Loop over each object, appending a table row with the relevant data each iteration.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON(url,
    function (json) {
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].User_Name + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].score + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].team + "</td>");
            $('table').append(tr);
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kkg3/)

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick reply- this definitely puts me on the right track. However when I replace the value of the json variable with $.getJSON(url) it does not seem to parse the array, console simply returns the whole object...

Comment: Thanks again- when I enter the url and run the script I am now getting "SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object" in the error console?

Comment: How to refresh the td for new data?

Comment: @pmandell I am using the code you provided in the Fiddle. However I only get table header and no data or table.

Comment: script injection vuln.

Comment: FYI: html on JSFiddle is  <table>
    <tr>
        <th>User_Name</th>
        <th>score</th>
        <th>team</th>
    </tr>
</table>

Answer (score 8):

You can use simple jQuery jPut plugin

http://plugins.jquery.com/jput/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var json = [{"name": "name1","score":"30"},{"name": "name2","score":"50"}];
//while running this code the template will be appended in your div with json data
$("#tbody").jPut({
    jsonData:json,
    //ajax_url:"youfile.json",  if you want to call from a json file
    name:"tbody_template",
});

});
</script>   

<div jput="tbody_template">
 <tr>
  <td>{{name}}</td>
  <td>{{score}}</td>
 </tr>
</div>

<table>
 <tbody id="tbody">
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6):

Loop over each object, push in string array and join them. Append in target table, it is better.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON(url,
function (json) {
    var tr=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        tr.push('<tr>');
        tr.push("<td>" + json[i].User_Name + "</td>");
        tr.push("<td>" + json[i].score + "</td>");
        tr.push("<td>" + json[i].team + "</td>");
        tr.push('</tr>');
    }
    $('table').append($(tr.join('')));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/index.html) with jQuery. KnockoutJS have smart data-binding features. By using the  [foreach binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) feature you can write your code like this example:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>Team</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: teams">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: User_Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: score "></td>
            <td data-bind="text: team "></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON(url,function (json) {
               ko.applyBindings({
                  teams: json
               });
          }
        });

    });
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/1gev51t2/) with your dummy data

Answer (score 2):

Make a HTML Table from a JSON array of Objects by extending $ as shown below

```
$.makeTable = function (mydata) {
            var table = $('<table border=1>');
            var tblHeader = "<tr>";
            for (var k in mydata[0]) tblHeader += "<th>" + k + "</th>";
            tblHeader += "</tr>";
            $(tblHeader).appendTo(table);
            $.each(mydata, function (index, value) {
                var TableRow = "<tr>";
                $.each(value, function (key, val) {
                    TableRow += "<td>" + val + "</td>";
                });
                TableRow += "</tr>";
                $(table).append(TableRow);
            });
            return ($(table));
        };
```

and use as follows:

```
var mydata = eval(jdata);
var table = $.makeTable(mydata);
$(table).appendTo("#TableCont");
```

where TableCont is some div

Answer (score 2):

This one is ugly, but just want to throw there some other options to the mix. This one has no loops. I use it for debugging purposes

```
var myObject = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:{a:1,b:2,c:3,e:{a:1}}}
var myStrObj = JSON.stringify(myObject)
var myHtmlTableObj = myStrObj.replace(/{/g,"<table><tr><td>").replace(/:/g,"</td><td>","g").replace(/,/g,"</td></tr><tr><td>","g").replace(/}/g,"</table>")

$('#myDiv').html(myHtmlTableObj)
```

Example:

```js
    var myObject = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:{a:1,b:2,c:3,e:{a:1}}}
    var myStrObj = JSON.stringify(myObject)
    var myHtmlTableObj = myStrObj.replace(/\"/g,"").replace(/{/g,"<table><tr><td>").replace(/:/g,"</td><td>","g").replace(/,/g,"</td></tr><tr><td>","g").replace(/}/g,"</table>")

    $('#myDiv').html(myHtmlTableObj)
```

```css
#myDiv table td{background:whitesmoke;border:1px solid lightgray}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'>table goes here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

another nice recursive way to generate HTML from a nested JSON object (currently not supporting arrays):

```
// generate HTML code for an object
var make_table = function(json, css_class='tbl_calss', tabs=1){
    // helper to tabulate the HTML tags. will return '\t\t\t' for num_of_tabs=3
    var tab = function(num_of_tabs){
        var s = '';
        for (var i=0; i<num_of_tabs; i++){
            s += '\t';
        }
        //console.log('tabbing done. tabs=' + tabs)
        return s;
    }
    // recursive function that returns a fixed block of <td>......</td>.
    var generate_td = function(json){ 
        if (!(typeof(json) == 'object')){
            // for primitive data - direct wrap in <td>...</td>
            return tab(tabs) + '<td>'+json+'</td>\n';
        }else{
            // recursive call for objects to open a new sub-table inside the <td>...</td>
            // (object[key] may be also an object)
            var s = tab(++tabs)+'<td>\n';
            s +=        tab(++tabs)+'<table class="'+css_class+'">\n';
            for (var k in json){
                s +=        tab(++tabs)+'<tr>\n';
                s +=          tab(++tabs)+'<td>' + k + '</td>\n';
                s +=                      generate_td(json[k]);
                s +=        tab(--tabs)+'</tr>' + tab(--tabs) + '\n';


            }
            // close the <td>...</td> external block
            s +=        tab(tabs--)+'</table>\n';
            s +=    tab(tabs--)+'</td>\n';
            return s;
        }
    }
    // construct the complete HTML code
    var html_code = '' ;
    html_code += tab(++tabs)+'<table class="'+css_class+'">\n';
    html_code +=   tab(++tabs)+'<tr>\n';
    html_code +=     generate_td(json);
    html_code +=   tab(tabs--)+'</tr>\n';
    html_code += tab(tabs--)+'</table>\n';
    return html_code;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to do the same thing, with or without jQuery:

```js
// jquery way
$(document).ready(function () {
    
  var json = [{"User_Name":"John Doe","score":"10","team":"1"},{"User_Name":"Jane Smith","score":"15","team":"2"},{"User_Name":"Chuck Berry","score":"12","team":"2"}];
        
  var tr;
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].User_Name + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].score + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].team + "</td>");
    $('table').first().append(tr);
  }  
});

// without jquery
function ready(){
 var json = [{"User_Name":"John Doe","score":"10","team":"1"},{"User_Name":"Jane Smith","score":"15","team":"2"},{"User_Name":"Chuck Berry","score":"12","team":"2"}];
  const table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[1];
  json.forEach((obj) => {
      const row = table.insertRow(-1)
    row.innerHTML = `
      <td>${obj.User_Name}</td>
      <td>${obj.score}</td>
      <td>${obj.team}</td>
    `;
  });
};

if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === "complete" : document.readyState !== "loading"){
  ready();
} else {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>User_Name</th>
        <th>score</th>
        <th>team</th>
    </tr>
</table>'
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>User_Name</th>
        <th>score</th>
        <th>team</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in a general solution in plain Vanilla JS. It works independently of the number of columns you have in your json.

```js
const myData = [{"User_Name":"John Doe","score":"10","team":"1"},{"User_Name":"Jane Smith","score":"15","team":"2"},{"User_Name":"Chuck Berry","score":"12","team":"2"}]

const createTable = (json) => {
  let table = document.getElementById('js-table')

  for (let row of json) {
    let newRow  = table.insertRow();
    for (let cell of Object.values(row)) {
      let newCell = newRow.insertCell();
      let newText  = document.createTextNode(cell);
      newCell.appendChild(newText);
    }     
  }
}

createTable(myData)
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="js-table">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time developing various reports. So, now I have an idea - create a web framework for building web reports. I have started here:

https://github.com/ColdSIce/ReportUI

Now it is an **angular 4** module. You can **pass your json** data to TableLayoutComponent and **get a HTML table** as result. Table already has fixed header. Also you can fix some your columns by default or by click. More there, you can customize table properties like background-color, font-color, row-height etc.

If you are interested you can join me in this project and help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another way to parse json object into Html table

```js
//EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER.
// ('Book ID', 'Book Name', 'Category' and 'Price')
var col = [];

for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
  for (var key in d[i]) {
if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
  col.push(key);
}
  }
}

// CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
var table = document.createElement("table");

// CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.
var tr = table.insertRow(-1);    // TABLE ROW.               
                 
for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
  var th = document.createElement("th");// TABLE HEADER.
  th.innerHTML = col[i];
  tr.appendChild(th);
}

// ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
  tr = table.insertRow(-1);

  for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
tabCell.innerHTML = d[i][col[j]];
  }
}

// FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
divContainer.innerHTML = "";
divContainer.appendChild(table);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will help a lot

```
function isObject(data){
    var tb = document.createElement("table");

    if(data !=null) {
        var keyOfobj = Object.keys(data);
        var ValOfObj = Object.values(data);

        for (var i = 0; i < keyOfobj.length; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            var key = document.createTextNode(keyOfobj[i]);

            td.appendChild(key);
            tr.appendChild(td);
            tb.appendChild(tr);

            if(typeof(ValOfObj[i]) == "object") {

                if(ValOfObj[i] !=null) {
                    tr.setAttribute("style","font-weight: bold");   
                    isObject(ValOfObj[i]);
                } else {
                    var td = document.createElement('td');
                    var value = document.createTextNode(ValOfObj[i]);

                    td.appendChild(value);
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                    tb.appendChild(tr);
                }
            } else {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                var value = document.createTextNode(ValOfObj[i]);

                td.appendChild(value);
                tr.appendChild(td);
                tb.appendChild(tr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This post is very much helpful to all of you

First Parse the json data by using jquery eval parser and then iterarate through jquery each function below is the code sniplet:

```
                var obj = eval("(" + data.d + ")");

                alert(obj);
                $.each(obj, function (index,Object) {

                    var Id = Object.Id;
                    var AptYear = Object.AptYear;
                    $("#ddlyear").append('<option value=' + Id + '>' + AptYear + '</option>').toString();
                });
```

Comment: the OP asked for a table not a dropdown list