# append data in popup using jquery php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, loops

Pop-up html:

```
<div class="row" id="get_uv_detail" style="display:none">
  <div class="box border">
    <div class="box-body">
      <div class="uv-more-detail" style="max-height:450px;padding-right:10px" ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In controller i have function that returns data like this:

```
[{"name":"p1"},{"name":"p2"}]
```

How can I append it in the pop-up?

I have to display data like this:

```
Name
-----
p1
p2
```

Here is my script:

```
.done(function(data) {
$('.uv-more-detail').append(data);
});
// pop-up display
bootbox.dialog({
          message: msg,
          title: title,
          buttons: {
            main: {
              label: "Close",
              className: "btn-primary",
              callback: function() {
                $(".bootbox").modal("hide");
              }
            }
          }
        });
```

Comment: You are trying to append `JSON` to `html`. Make html from `JSON` and then do `append` :)

Comment: so how can i append ?

Comment: First try with searching over stackoverflow. if you found any problem then other can help.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi i tried this: `var res = JSON.parse(data);
  $.each(res, function(key, index){
           $('.uv-more-detail').append(index);
         });` but no luck

Comment: You should refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066636/parsing-json-objects-for-html-table?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @ParthTrivedi thanx have solved it with the link you gave..

Answer (score 0):

This is the same answer as link provided by @ParthTrivedi:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON(url,
    function (json) {
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name+ "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].date+ "</td>");
            $('table').append(tr);
        }
    });
});
```

For more answers: [Parsing JSON objects for HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066636/parsing-json-objects-for-html-table)