# Trying to Parse Json to a HTML Table

Tags: html, json, parsing

Well, I've been at this for 3 days now and I haven't figured this out yet.

I'm trying to grab the json from this [API](http://census.daybreakgames.com/json/status?game=h1z1) and trying to parse it to a HTML table, but I'm having trouble. Could anyone help/point me in the right direction?

This is the API I'm trying to grab [here](http://census.daybreakgames.com/json/status?game=h1z1)

```
http://census.daybreakgames.com/json/status?game=h1z1
```

Here's the Code i've tried to do.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script>
    $(function() {
       var entries = [];
       var dmJSON = "http://census.daybreakgames.com/json/status?game=h1z1";
       $.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
       $.each(data.entries, function(i, f) {
       var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.region_code + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.title + "</td>" + "<td> " + f.status + "</td>" +  "<td>" + f.age + "</td>" + "</tr>"
   $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
   });
  });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
<table id= "entrydata" border="1">
 <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Region Code</th>
    <th>Game</th>
<th>Server Stauts</th>
    <th>Time</th>
</thead>
  <tbody>

 </tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Show us what you already tried

Comment: How are you parsing it to HTML? HTML itself is a static language and can't process data that way. You can use Java Scripts to achieve what you are trying to do.

See if this helps 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066636/parsing-json-objects-for-html-table

Comment: put your efforts here for better help

Answer (score 0):

The main reason your code doesnt work is you put a `data.entries` param for the `each` function which is undefined. That has to represent a valid key from the json api.

There is two main keys inside the api (for this instance they are `Live` and `Test`) so you have to put an each loop inside another one. Then you need to use `i` to get the name, not `f`.

```
var dmJSON = "http://census.daybreakgames.com/json/status?game=h1z1";
$.getJSON(dmJSON, function(data) {
  $.each(data.h1z1, function(i, f) {
    $.each(f, function(i, f) {
        var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + i + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.region_code + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.title + "</td>" + "<td> " + f.status + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.age + "</td>" + "</tr>"
        $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: It still does not work, Nothing will show up in the table.