# Looping over objects in array, display data from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, foreach

## Objective

- I'm looking to loop over objects in an array so that each school using `html()` has their name, district and percentages in english, math, science and social studies reflected from the data in `schools.js`
- **Problem:** Right now, I'm only getting the last school in the array
- Is it possible to do this without a `data-id`? attached to each of the schools or is that actually necessary to identify which school is which?

### scripts.js

```
    // Generate numbers from 1 through 20
    for(var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
        var schoolID = i + 1
        console.log(schoolID);

        // Schools
        var schoolName = $(".school__name").html(schools[schoolID].name); // Name
        var schoolDistrict = $(".school__district").html(schools[schoolID].district); // District
        // var schoolCrest = // $(".school__image").attr("src", schools[schoolID].crest) // Crest

        // Percentage
        var percentEnglish = $(".school__district").html(schools[schoolID].english); // English
        var percentMath = $(".school__district").html(schools[schoolID].math); // Math
        var percentScience = $(".school__district").html(schools[schoolID].science); // Science
        var percentSocial = $(".school__district").html(schools[schoolID].social); // Social Science
    }
```

### school.js (There are 20 schools in total)

```
var schools = [
  {
    "name": "school1",
    "district": "district1",
    "crest": "",
    "location": "",
    "percentEnglish": "1%",
    "percentMath": "21%",
    "percentScience": "41%",
    "percentSocial": "61%"
  },
  {
    "name": "school2",
    "district": "district2",
    "crest": "",
    "location": "",
    "percentEnglish": "2%",
    "percentMath": "22%",
    "percentScience": "42%",
    "percentSocial": "62%"
  }];
```

### index.html

```
<div class="widget high-school">
    <div class="widget__info">
        <p class="widget__category">High school</p>
        <p class="widget__title">Missouri Assessment Program standouts</p>
    </div>

    <div class="widget__buttons">
        <p class="widget__rank">Rank by:</p>
        <button class="btn btn-english is-selected">English</button>
        <button class="btn btn-math">Math</button>
        <button class="btn btn-science">Science</button>
        <button class="btn btn-social">Social Studies</button>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="schools">
            <div class="school" data-id="1">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="3">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="4">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="5">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="6">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="7">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="8">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="9">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="10">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="11">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="12">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="13">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="14">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="15">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="16">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="17">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="18">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="19">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="20">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->
        </div><!-- schools -->
    </div>
```

Comment: show the html please and are you trying to set or get the data?

Comment: @depperm Added in the HTML

Comment: how do you want to link up the json data with the existing html? currently youre using a class selector, which matches many elements, but calling `.html()` will update them all.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yx9mtnv8/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is by using a class selector, many elements are selected. When you use `.html()` it does not know which element you want to target.

You can solve this easily by using `.eq()` to target a specific element by index - the same index as you're using in the json array.

```js
var schools = [
  {
    "name": "school1",
    "district": "district1",
    "crest": "",
    "location": "",
    "percentEnglish": "1%",
    "percentMath": "21%",
    "percentScience": "41%",
    "percentSocial": "61%"
  },
  {
    "name": "school2",
    "district": "district2",
    "crest": "",
    "location": "",
    "percentEnglish": "2%",
    "percentMath": "22%",
    "percentScience": "42%",
    "percentSocial": "62%"
  }];

for(var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
        
        // Schools
        $(".school__name").eq(i).html(schools[i].name); // Name
        $(".school__district").eq(i).html(schools[i].district); // District
        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget high-school">
    <div class="widget__info">
        <p class="widget__category">High school</p>
        <p class="widget__title">Missouri Assessment Program standouts</p>
    </div>

    <div class="widget__buttons">
        <p class="widget__rank">Rank by:</p>
        <button class="btn btn-english is-selected">English</button>
        <button class="btn btn-math">Math</button>
        <button class="btn btn-science">Science</button>
        <button class="btn btn-social">Social Studies</button>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="schools">
            <div class="school" data-id="1">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> 
        </div><!-- schools -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some html template in javascript and concatenate there your changeable data and append to parent element on each time of itaration

```js
var schools = [
  {
    "name": "school1",
    "district": "district1",
    "crest": "",
    "location": "",
    "percentEnglish": "1%",
    "percentMath": "21%",
    "percentScience": "41%",
    "percentSocial": "61%"
  },
  {
    "name": "school2",
    "district": "district2",
    "crest": "",
    "location": "",
    "percentEnglish": "2%",
    "percentMath": "22%",
    "percentScience": "42%",
    "percentSocial": "62%"
  }];


// Generate numbers from 1 through 20
    for(var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
        var schoolID = i
        console.log(schoolID);

        // Schools
        var school = $(".school__details");
        
        school.append(
                    '<div class="school__name">'+schools[schoolID].name+'</div>'+
                    '<div class="school__district">'+schools[schoolID].district+'</div>'+
                    '<hr />'
                    )
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget high-school">
    <div class="widget__info">
        <p class="widget__category">High school</p>
        <p class="widget__title">Missouri Assessment Program standouts</p>
    </div>

    <div class="widget__buttons">
        <p class="widget__rank">Rank by:</p>
        <button class="btn btn-english is-selected">English</button>
        <button class="btn btn-math">Math</button>
        <button class="btn btn-science">Science</button>
        <button class="btn btn-social">Social Studies</button>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="schools">
            <div class="school" data-id="1">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

          </div>
    </div>
```

[Parsing JSON objects for HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066636/parsing-json-objects-for-html-table)
someone has already asked that kind of question

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is replacing the HTML in the same element for each school in your loop - that is why you only see the last school. You would need to create a new set of HTML elements for each school (clone & append would help there) to prevent overwriting the previous school.