# How to parse json into html table?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to parse json data into a html table int format of :

```
project title         EAC     BAC    Overrun    Percentage

Project1              0 Day   0 Day   0             15%
closed
18/07/2016-18/08/2017


Project 2             350 Day 15 Day 15             30%
closed
05/02/2016-12/09/2022
```

I found this answer [Parsing JSON objects for HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066636/parsing-json-objects-for-html-table) which I used to 
write this code:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (result) {

             var str = JSON.stringify(result);
             obj = JSON.parse(str);
             for(var i = 0; i < obj.value.length; i++) {
                 tr = $('<tr/>');
                  tr.append("<td class=\"project_title\">" + obj.value[i].name + "</td>" + "<td class=\"project_title\">" + obj.value[i].eac + "</td>" + "<td class=\"project_title\">" +  obj.value[i].bac + "</td>" + "<td class=\"project_title\">" +  obj.value[i].overrun + "<td class=\"project_title\">" + obj.value[i].percentage +  "</td>");
                 $('table').append(tr);
             }
            });
```

But I didn't understand how to add the status of the project and the date in the same cell over Project title.
For example for `Project 1` I should add such status `closed` and the date of begin and end of the project `18/07/2016-18/08/2017`.
How can I add these options to each project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert json data to a html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table)

Comment: provide your JSON please?

Comment: Well if you want it in the same cell, just put it in the same cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `</br>` between the fields you want in the first cell:

```
tr.append("<td class=\"project_title\">" + obj.value[i].name + "</br>" + obj.value[i].attribute1 + "</br>" + obj.value[i].attribute2 + "</td>");
```

It may work in your case.