# How to use json data in html

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have json with js file `list.js` and I am trying to get the data from it in HTML file `index.html`.Tell me please how to connect it with HTML.

Here's my json with js file:

```
 $(function () {

      var categories = {
        menu: [{
          title: "animals",
          children: [{
            title: "insects",
            children: [{
              title: "ant",
              title: "bee",
              title: "fly"
            }]
          },
          {
            title: "mammals",
            children: [{
              title: "bear",
              title: "platypus",
              title: "tiger"
            }]

          },
          {
            title: "reptiles",
            children: [{
              title: "crocodile",
              title: "turtle"
            }]
          }
          ]
        },
        {

          title: "fruits",
          children: [{
            title: "apple",
            title: "pineapple",
            title: "pear"
          }]

        },
        {
          title: "vegetables",
          children: [{
            title: "potato",
            title: "tomato",
            title: "carrot"
          }]
        }]
      };
      var getMenuItem = function (itemData) {
        var item = $("<li>")
          .append(
          $("<a>", {
            html: itemData.title
          }));
        if (itemData.children) {
          var childrenList = $("<ul>");
          $.each(itemData.children, function () {
            childrenList.append(getMenuItem(this));
          });
          item.append(childrenList);
        }
        return item;
      };

      var $menu = $("#menu");
      $.each(categories.menu, function () {
        $menu.append(
          getMenuItem(this)
        );
      });
      $menu.menu();
});
```

The idea is to make unfolding menu to show these types Animals-Insects-ant,fly,bee;Mammals-bear,platypus,tiger;Reptiles-crocodile,turtle;.Please help, I am new to this field.:(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON objects for HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066636/parsing-json-objects-for-html-table)

Comment: Nope, Im using json and js in 1 file and I am trying to make an unfolding menu with these categories not a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post explains very well you you can combine an external JSON file with an html file: [How to read an external local JSON file in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript)

However! What you are having is not an json file. What i would suggest is getting your JSON data, store it within its own file and use the .json extension and then follow the example shown in the post

Comment: Can't I use both the json and js in 1 file? I mean  if i let only the json data I must add quotes over everything right?I am not so sure how to do that.

Comment: You could convert `categories` to json by using `JSON.stringify(categories)`. The JSON object is something that comes standard with javascript.