# Convert json to html table output in javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get the JSON output on the UI using the below function

```
$("#idvar").click(function(){
  var d1 = document.getElementById("dText");
  var d2 = document.getElementById("dJson");
  var mytext = d1.textContent;
  alert(mytext);
  $.post(
    url,
    {doc: mytext},
    function(data) {
      console.log(Object.keys(data).length);
      d2.textContent = data;
    }
  );
});
```

where `d1` is the displaying the uploaded input document, `d2` for the output generated from processing the document on a model.  Currently, I am getting json format.  I tried to implement the codes in these posts ([Parsing JSON objects for HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066636/parsing-json-objects-for-html-table), [Convert json data to a html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table)), but I get `[object, Object]` in the text area.  Is there a way to convert the json to table.

In the URL text area i get

```
 [{"tag":"a1","relevance":0.5},
  {"tag":"a2","relevance":0.3},
  {"tag":"c3","relevance":0.2},{"tag":"d3,
   ...
```

Instead, I was hoping to get

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BQNE.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Check out this example http://jsfiddle.net/7MRx6/338/

Comment: @nikunjMnage  I tried the example on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066636/parsing-json-objects-for-html-table, but it gives [object, Object] as display.  Inside the function(data), the 'tr' variable was created

Comment: Share with us what the returned JSON looks like. You can see it by changing `d2.textContent = data;` for `d2.textContent = JSON.stringify(data);`

Comment: @Piyin  I added the 'plugin json2html',  with transform, now i get output like `<li>a1 (0.2)</li><li> a2 (0.3)</li>` used `$('#d2').html(json2html.transform(data, transform));` where `var transform = {'<>':'li','html':'${tag} (${relevance})'};`  Is it possible to remove those tags from the output

Comment: Which tags do you want to remove?

Comment: @Piyin the 'd2' is the id of the textarea where I am displaying.  I thought that json2html gives a nice table on the ui.  But, instead it gives with tags i.e. `<li></li>`  So, I removed it in `var transform = {'<>': '','html':'${tag} (${relevance})'};`  Now it gives `<>a1 (0.2)</>`  Sorry, I am new to javascript

Comment: @Piyin I have been trying for almost 3 hours.  Didn't know that this is too difficult

Comment: Oh, well, I've never used that plugin, but perhaps you're able to configure it with: `var transform = {'<>': 'tr','html':'<td>${tag}</td><td>${relevance}</td>'};` and make sure `d2` references a `<table>` element. Also, it's not that difficult to do by hand (without the plugin) it's just important to know the structure

Comment: @Piyin Thanks, let me try that one.  If it works, you could post as an answer and will accept that

Comment: @Piyin The 'd2' is referencing to `textarea` i.e. `<textarea id="d2" class="form-control" rows="25" cols="100"></textarea>`

Comment: Change the `id` attribute of the `textarea` (to something different to `d2`) and put this below that line: `<table id="d2"></table>`

Comment: @Piyin Now, I get that `<table id="tbl"></table>` in the display output.  Sorry, I am lost

Comment: @Piyin may be tables are not meant to be inside textarea

Comment: No, wait, I didn't say you should but the `table` inside the `textarea`. You should remove the `textarea` completely. And only have a line like `<table id="d2"></table>`. Then all the code should work (Hi, lost, I'm dad)

Comment: @Piyin  Thanks, tried that, but there is now no output displayed.

Comment: Oh, shit, I messed it up. The `table` should look like `<table id="dJson"></table>`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you updated your answer. I'm going to give you an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should traverse the data and print it in table format. First, make sure the element with id `dJson` is a `<table>` element. Then, you can change your `success` callback to something like:

```
function(data) {
  console.log(Object.keys(data).length);
  var html = '<tr><th>Tag</th><th>Relevance</th></tr>';
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    html +=
      '<tr>' +
        '<td>' +
          data[i].tag +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
          data[i].relevance +
        '</td>' +
      '</tr>'
    ;
  }
  d2.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Here you have a working example (without the `$.post` call): https://jsfiddle.net/cLbqmwa4/

Comment: The `<table id="dJson"></table>` was not working.  So, i changed it to `div` `<div id="dJson"></div>` and also `$('#dJson').html(html);`  Now, it works, thanks

Comment: It looks like you have CSS problems in the code, the `<table>` should work without problems. If you check the JSFiddle link you see how it works with `<table>` but not with `<div>`. Anyway, glad it worked for you and you're welcome