# Dynamic JSON object to Html Table

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have gone through this solution [Parsing JSON objects for HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066636/parsing-json-objects-for-html-table) . But in this solution Object keys are pre-defined when creating table. But I have some json data which can have random data.

Somtimes it can be :

```
var data = {
"C#": 2172738,
"CSS": 9390,
"HTML": 135085,
"Java": 337323
}
```

Or, Sometimes it can be:

```
var data = {
"Go": 2172738,
"Ruby": 9390,
"Dart": 135085
}
```

That means keys are not fixed. That data object can be dynamic. I want to convert the dynamic object to html table. Let's say, I have a table where **thead** is defined and **tbody** is empty:

```
<table id="_myTable">
 <thead>
  <th>Language</th>
  <th>Line of Codes</th>
</thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How should I approach to insert that dynamic object **data** to **tbody**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [element.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to accomplish your task:

```js
var data = {
    "C#": 2172738,
    "CSS": 9390,
    "HTML": 135085,
    "Java": 337323
}
for (key in data) {
    var tr = `<tr><td>${key}</td><td>${data[key]}</td></tr>`;
    document.querySelector('#_myTable tbody').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', tr);
}
```

```html
<table id="_myTable">
    <thead>
    <th>Language</th>
    <th>Line of Codes</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys(data)` to get all of keys for "language" table data and `Object.values(data)` or `Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key])` for "line of codes" table data.