# Completely stuck on how to display my JSON in HTML. Edit: I know how i want to format it, I just can't get it to output anything but raw JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, api

I've been working on this for hours, searching everywhere, can't seem to solve it. I've left the API URL in, so if you want to take a look (it's public). I'm tired, so if I don't make sense, let me know. I'm trying to basically make a custom layout for the news. But I can't do anything with it, I just have the raw JSON, and I've tried a lot. If you could just give an example of something like a header with the news article name, or something simple, I'll figure it out, but for now, I'm frustrated and running in circles, haha. Thanks!

```
{
 "location": {
"long": -106.346771,
"countryOrRegion": "Canada",
"provinceOrState": null,
"county": null,
"isoCode": "CA",
"lat": 56.130366
},
"updatedDateTime": "2020-03-31T04:46:00.3795966Z",
"news": [
 {
    "path": "_news/2020-03-31-canada-post-workers-customers-seeing-heightened-safeguards.md",
    "title": "Canada Post workers, customers seeing heightened safeguards",
    "excerpt": "COVID-19 ...",
    "heat": null,
    "tags": [
      "CA"
    ]  ,
    "type": "article",
    "webUrl": "https://nnsl.com/yellowknifer/canada-post-workers-customers-seeing-heightened-safeguards/",
    "ampWebUrl": null,
    "cdnAmpWebUrl": null,
    "publishedDateTime": "2020-03-30T21:00:00-07:00",
    "updatedDateTime": null,
    "provider": {
      "name": "Northern News Services",
      "domain": "nnsl.com",
      "images": null,
      "publishers": null,
      "authors": null
    },
    "images": null,
    "locale": "en-us",
    "categories": [
      "news"
    ],
    "topics": [
      "Coronavirus in Canada",
      "Coronavirus"
    ]
  },
  {
    "path": "_news/2020-03-31-in-canada-and-abroad-covid-19-super-spreaders-could-be-anywhere.md",
    "title": "In Canada and abroad, COVID-19 super-spreaders could be anywhere",
    "excerpt": "In Canada, while no specific individual has yet been identified as super-spreader ... 
Scientists are researching how much of a role silent carriers of COVID-19 - those who exhibit no symptoms - play in unknowingly spreading the disease. This is why self-isolation is important, Riskin said. \"It’s a reminder that for Canadians, we all have ...",
     "heat": null,
    " ...etc
```

Oops, you need a key to view the file. I'll paste in one entry. It is free.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
countryOrRegion: font-size: 20px;

</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="demo"></div>


<script>
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://api.smartable.ai/coronavirus/news/CA",
  // Request headers
  beforeSend: function(xhrObj) {
    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Subscription-Key", "my free key");
    },
})

.done(function (data) {

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJSON;

})
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: its up to you to decide how the news is laid out. via cards or tabular, its up to you. use an html free template if you'd like

Comment: I can't get any of the news to display in HTML. I know how I want to do it, but I can't get it to parse/decode. No matter what I do I get the same old raw form.

Comment: I know you're tired and probably frustrated with this but if you could show what you've tried, then we can help you get it working. Try searching for something like _"display JSON in HTML table"_, there's plenty of posts like that. Here's one good example ~ [Parsing JSON objects for HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066636/parsing-json-objects-for-html-table)

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` turns your data into JSON. While `JSON.parse()` turns it into an Object which you can work with. Add the `dataType: 'json'` property to your `$.ajax` options to receive data as pre-parsed. Then you can use the object in any way you want.

Comment: I've tried a lot of Show in HTML table,  jQuery.each(data.results, function(i, val) { code } (blank page),   <?php 
$JSON = file_get_contents("https://corona.lmao.ninja/all");
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($JSON, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    (blank page),  <?php  

$url = 'apis';
$data = file_get_contents($url)
$characters = json_decode($data); 


foreach ($characters as $character) { run }

Comment: I've tried different variations of what I posted above, none of them work. Blank page.

Comment: To Emiel, thanks, that makes sense. I get an error and blank page when I go from stringify to parse. I get "VM501:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)" which seems to mean its a JS object.

Comment: `<style>countryOrRegion: font-size: 20px;</style>` looks like an odd style declaration syntax to me.

Comment: I know, I was screwing with something and didn't remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using the response as it is?
I altered your code to use a free API call from reqres.in, then using specific information from the result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
countryOrRegion: font-size: 20px;

</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="demo">
    <p id="first-name"></p>
    <p id="last-name"></p>
</div>


<script>
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://reqres.in/api/users/1",
  // Request headers
  beforeSend: function(xhrObj) {
    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Subscription-Key", "my free key");
    },
})

.done(function (data) {
  console.log('Your response', data)
  document.getElementById("first-name").innerHTML = data.data.first_name;
  document.getElementById("last-name").innerHTML = data.data.last_name;
})
</script>

</body>
```

So you could use `data.location.long`, `data.location.lat` or whatever you need to show from your API call response.

Comment: Thank you, with some fiddling, that works out well. Greatly appreciated, cheers!

Comment: Your welcome. Finally I can write comments, win win ;)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a template builder function like this:

```
function BuildNewsTemplate(obj) {
    let str = "<div class='card'>";//outer
    str += `<h2>${obj.title}</h2>`;
    str += `<p>${obj.publishedDateTime}</p>`;
    str += `<a href='${obj.webUrl}'>Read More...</p>`;
    str += "</div>";

    $('#demo').append(str);
}


then in your ajax response you can do this:

.done(function (data) {
   for(let i=0;i<data.news.length;i++){
     BuildNewsTemplate(data.news[i]);
   }    
})
```