# Display all data from json response in HTML

Tags: javascript

Here's an example JSON response. I would like to display each of these as search results in HTML. I'm thinking of a `forEach` loop however I can't wrap my head around how it would work. Example below.

```
"data": [{
      "CountryISO2": "US",
      "name": "Example",
      "Address1": "Example",
      "City": "example",
   },
   {

      "CountryISO2": "example",
      "name": "example",
      "Address1": "example",
      "City": "example",
   },
```

**Javascript:**

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();.......

response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

response.data.forEach(function(index) {
   const teamName = response.data.name; //the name in JSON
   const nameDiv = document.getElementById('clubname');
   nameDiv.innerHTML = teamName;
});
```

I would essentially like to display all the results for name on my page. I'm pretty new to JS. I can't use jQuery in my project.

Comment: you want to make a table? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61142336/8029211

Comment: if you use `forEach` you have to write your code another way. Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach to learn the proper way to use `forEach`.

Comment: here, you pass a callback function to `foreach`, with a `index` argument, but never use it, and refer to the whole object being "looped"...

Comment: And also, IDs must be unique to a document, so you're setting the `innerHTML` of the same element in every iteration...

Comment: you should obtain `teamname` with `function(element){ var teamName = element.name }`, element being set at each loop turn with each object litteral from `data` property

Comment: please rewrite all your code with suggested edits

Comment: There are many questions about building HTML from "JSON" (which is actually just arrays and objects once you run JSON.parse on it). Is there something you don't understand about those questions' answers?

Comment: Go with React! (also don't use var, use let and const)

Comment: You shouldn't only assign the index for the function but also assign the `currentValue` for the items in it like `response.data.forEach(function(currentValue,index)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new element in JS with:
document.createElement("Element You Want To Create Goes Here")

You can than push what you want into this newly created element with ".innerHTML"

You will then need to append this created element to the body or it will just sit there.

Hope this helps friend.

Snippet

```
    data.forEach(function(index) {
            var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            newDiv.innerHTML = index.name;
            document.body.appendChild(newDiv)
        })
```

Full Code

```
let data =  [
    {
    "CountryISO2": "US",
    "name": "Example",
    "Address1": "Example",
    "City": "example",
    },
    {

    "CountryISO3": "example",
    "name": "example",
    "Address1": "example",
    "City": "example",
    }
]


data.forEach(function(index) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.innerHTML = index.name;
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv)
})
```