# Having separate arrays, how to extract value based on the column name?

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to extract data from some JSON with JQ - I have already got it down to the last level of data that I need to extract from, but I am completely stumped as to how to proceed with how this part of the data is formatted.

An example would be:

```
{
  "values": [
    [
      1483633677,
      42
    ]
  ],
  "columns": [
    "time",
    "count_value"
  ],
  "name": "response_time_error"
}
```

I would want to extract just the value for a certain column (e.g. `count_value`) and I can extract it by using `[-1]` in this specific case, but I want to select the column by its name in case they change in the future.

Comment: So iterate the columns array and test for the required string value. When you get a hit note the index and your answer is values[index].

Comment: Plenty of examples of how to iterate array here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489288/how-to-loop-through-json-array

Answer (score 1):

If you're only extracting a single value and the arrays will always correspond with eachother, you could find the index in the `columns` array then use that index into the `values` array.

It seems like `values` is an array of rows with those values.  Assuming you want to output the values of all rows with the selected column:

```
$ jq --arg col 'count_value' '.values[][.columns | index($col)]' input.json
```

Comment: How can I construct JSON below from this

    {
    "time": 1483633677,
    "count_value": 42
    }

Comment: In that case, you could use `transpose/0` to match corresponding items in the arrays. Then use that to construct that object. `[.columns,.values] | reduce transpose[] as [$key,$value] ({}; .[$key] = $value)`

Comment: perfect .. Thank you. below worked

'[.columns,.values[0]] | reduce transpose[] as [$key,$value] ({}; .[$key] = $value)'

how to output array of object for multiple values array like 

{
  "values": [
    [
      1483633677,
      42
    ],
    [
      1483633678,
      43
    ]
  ],
  "columns": [
    "time",
    "count_value"
  ],
  "name": "response_time_error"
}

Answer (score 1):

If the specified column name does not exist in .columns, then Jeff's filter will fail with a rather obscure error message.  It might therefore be preferable to check whether the column name is found.  Here is an illustration of how to do so:

```
 jq --arg col count_value '
   (.columns | index($col)) as $ix
   | if $ix then .values[][$ix] else empty end' input.json
```

If you want an informative error message to be printed, then replace `empty` with something like:

```
error("specified column name, \($col), not found")
```