# Use AJAX to update data retrive from databse(mysql)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I would like to get data from a database using a "date-picker" to select the date range of data, the problem is that my data is not being saved on the `var datapoints`, but the `console.log(result)` shows the data very well, my code is something like this:

test.js

```
jQuery.extend({
dataRange: function(start, end) {
        $.ajax({    
            type: "POST",
            url: "some.php",             
            dataType: "json",  
            data: {date1: start, date2: end},
            success: function(data){                    
                var result = JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log(result); //shows the data well
                return result;
            }
        });

    }
});
//initial data
var start = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
var end = moment().subtract(7, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var datapointsP;
$.dataRange(start, end)
  .done(function(data) { //get error here
datapointsP = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(datapointsP); // this should print the necessary data
})
.fail(function(xhr) {
 console.log('error', xhr);
});
```

Then on some.php

```
$start = $_POST['date1'];
$end = $_POST['date2'];
$query =  "select * from table where date between '" . $end . "' and '" . $start . "'";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$data = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++){
    $data[] = 0;
}

while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
     $data[$row['horas']] = ((int)$row['pot']);
}
$post_data = json_encode($data);
echo $post_data;
}
```

PD: I still can't add the datepicker because of this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you expect to be able to use a variable out of its scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your returning result from dataRange in wron way you should return result under `ajax success`

```
 jQuery.extend({
 dataRange: function(start, end) {
        $.ajax({    
            type: "POST",
            url: "some.php",             
            dataType: "json",  
            data: {date1: start, date2: end},
            success: function(data){                    
                var result = JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log(result); //shows the data well
                return result; 
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: you are totally right!, now it seems that my <code>JSON.parse($.dataRange(start, end))</code> is having problems

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at test.js:95

What does this means?

Comment: when datatype is `json` then please do not use `json parse` as it is not necessary as u are already getting json value @Santiago Center

Comment: on some.php I print an json_encode($array), How can I retrive it as array on test.js?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489288/how-to-loop-through-json-array

Answer (score 1):

The `$.ajax` performs an asynchronous `HTTP (Ajax) request`. It means that `$.ajax` is not executed in the same Javascript thread.

So, the dataRange function is executed and it passes the `$.ajax call` to your browser. Then it goes to the next statement and returns the result. Now, as result is not declared, it throws the `Uncaught ReferenceError`.

Even if you return the result from the `success` handler, the variable `datapoints` will be `undefined` as the execution of data range was already completed and returned `undefined`.

To solve this, you need to make use of `promise`. `$.ajax` returns a promise which can be used to retrieve the data returned from the request. Check out this [link](http://blog.revathskumar.com/2016/06/why-i-prefer-ajax-promise.html) to understand more about promise and $.ajax.

```js
jQuery.extend({
dataRange: function(start, end) {
        return $.ajax({    
            type: "POST",
            url: "some.php",             
            dataType: "json",  
            data: {date1: start, date2: end},
            success: function(data){                    
                var result = JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log(result); //shows the data well
                return result;
            }
        });
    }
});
//initial data
var start = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
var end = moment().subtract(7, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var datapoints;
$.dataRange(start, end)
  .done(function(data) {
    datapoints = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(datapoints); // this should print the necessary data
  })
  .fail(function(xhr) {
    console.log('error', xhr);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined

seems like I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you returning $.ajax from the dataRange function?

Comment: the result is and json array, which can be seen in some.php

Comment: So, the result variable is correct, right?
Can you tell me what is shown when you do
console.log($.dataRange(start, end));

Comment: it returns "undefined" but the console.log(result); returns a string like this [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,...,]

Comment: my bad, I was using async: false on the ajax, now it returns the same string as console.log(result)

Comment: No, still geting the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined

Comment: Are you sure you are having 'return $.ajax' in your dataRange function. This is must for the code to work. Please confirm

Comment: You have not added `return $.ajax` yet. Please copy my code completely and paste it. It will work.

Comment: Let me know if you still have any issues?