# Trying to get all like objects

Tags: javascript, object

```
{"drinks":[{"idDrink":"13060","strDrink":"Margarita","strVideo":null,"strCategory":"Ordinary Drink","strIBA":"Contemporary Classics","strAlcoholic":"Alcoholic","strGlass":"Cocktail glass","strInstructions":"Rub the rim of the glass with the lime slice to make the salt stick to it. Take care to moisten only the outer rim and sprinkle the salt on it. The salt should present to the lips of the imbiber and never mix into the cocktail. Shake the other ingredients with ice, then carefully pour into the glass.","strDrinkThumb":"http:\/\/www.thecocktaildb.com\/images\/media\/drink\/wpxpvu1439905379.jpg","strIngredient1":"Tequila","strIngredient2":"Triple sec","strIngredient3":"Lime juice","strIngredient4":"Salt","strIngredient5":"","strIngredient6":"","strIngredient7":"","strIngredient8":"","strIngredient9":"","strIngredient10":"","strIngredient11":"","strIngredient12":"","strIngredient13":"","strIngredient14":"","strIngredient15":"","strMeasure1":"1 1\/2 oz ","strMeasure2":"1\/2 oz ","strMeasure3":"1 oz ","strMeasure4":"","strMeasure5":"","strMeasure6":"","strMeasure7":"","strMeasure8":"","strMeasure9":"","strMeasure10":"","strMeasure11":"","strMeasure12":"","strMeasure13":"","strMeasure14":"","strMeasure15":"","dateModified":"2015-08-18 14:42:59"}]}
```

That is the json data but rather than do this:

```
des.innerHTML = cocktails.strIngredient1 + " " + cocktails.strMeasure1 + " - " + cocktails.strIngredient2 + " " + cocktails.strMeasure2 + " - " + cocktails.strIngredient3 + " " + cocktails.strMeasure3 + " - " + cocktails.strIngredient4 + " " + cocktails.strMeasure4 + "  " + cocktails.strIngredient5 + "  " + cocktails.strMeasure5 + "  " + cocktails.strInstructions;
```

I'd rather find a much neater way to do this. I've tried looping but being new to this I can't seem to find one that works. objects that are numbered are really new to me and not sure how to process them ie - strIngredient12 or strMeasure7

Comment: For looping a JSON array check it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489288/how-to-loop-through-json-array

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to take advantage of some ES6 you could [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the vales of the object, which will cut down on repetition and place them in a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which will remove the need to concatenate so many strings.

```js
const des = document.getElementById('des');

const cocktails = {
  "drinks": [{
    "idDrink": "13060",
    "strDrink": "Margarita",
    "strVideo": null,
    "strCategory": "Ordinary Drink",
    "strIBA": "Contemporary Classics",
    "strAlcoholic": "Alcoholic",
    "strGlass": "Cocktail glass",
    "strInstructions": "Rub the rim of the glass with the lime slice to make the salt stick to it. Take care to moisten only the outer rim and sprinkle the salt on it. The salt should present to the lips of the imbiber and never mix into the cocktail. Shake the other ingredients with ice, then carefully pour into the glass.",
    "strDrinkThumb": "http:\/\/www.thecocktaildb.com\/images\/media\/drink\/wpxpvu1439905379.jpg",
    "strIngredient1": "Tequila",
    "strIngredient2": "Triple sec",
    "strIngredient3": "Lime juice",
    "strIngredient4": "Salt",
    "strIngredient5": "",
    "strIngredient6": "",
    "strIngredient7": "",
    "strIngredient8": "",
    "strIngredient9": "",
    "strIngredient10": "",
    "strIngredient11": "",
    "strIngredient12": "",
    "strIngredient13": "",
    "strIngredient14": "",
    "strIngredient15": "",
    "strMeasure1": "1 1\/2 oz ",
    "strMeasure2": "1\/2 oz ",
    "strMeasure3": "1 oz ",
    "strMeasure4": "",
    "strMeasure5": "",
    "strMeasure6": "",
    "strMeasure7": "",
    "strMeasure8": "",
    "strMeasure9": "",
    "strMeasure10": "",
    "strMeasure11": "",
    "strMeasure12": "",
    "strMeasure13": "",
    "strMeasure14": "",
    "strMeasure15": "",
    "dateModified": "2015-08-18 14:42:59"
  }]
}

const { strIngredient1, strMeasure1, strIngredient2, strMeasure2, strIngredient3, strMeasure3, strIngredient4, strMeasure4, strIngredient5, strMeasure5, strInstructions } = cocktails.drinks[0];

des.innerHTML = `${strIngredient1} ${strMeasure1} ${strIngredient2} ${strMeasure2} ${strIngredient3} ${strMeasure3} ${strIngredient4} ${strMeasure4} ${strIngredient5} ${strMeasure5} ${strInstructions}`;
```

```html
<div id="des"></div>
```

Comment: That works beautifully!!! Thank you so much!  Learning new ways is always the best!!

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to mark this answer as correct if you deem it so.

Answer (score 0):

Does this sound like a good approach.

```
let drinks = {"drinks":[{"idDrink":"13060","strDrink":"Margarita","strVideo":null,"strCategory":"Ordinary Drink","strIBA":"Contemporary Classics","strAlcoholic":"Alcoholic","strGlass":"Cocktail glass","strInstructions":"Rub the rim of the glass with the lime slice to make the salt stick to it. Take care to moisten only the outer rim and sprinkle the salt on it. The salt should present to the lips of the imbiber and never mix into the cocktail. Shake the other ingredients with ice, then carefully pour into the glass.","strDrinkThumb":"http:\/\/www.thecocktaildb.com\/images\/media\/drink\/wpxpvu1439905379.jpg","strIngredient1":"Tequila","strIngredient2":"Triple sec","strIngredient3":"Lime juice","strIngredient4":"Salt","strIngredient5":"","strIngredient6":"","strIngredient7":"","strIngredient8":"","strIngredient9":"","strIngredient10":"","strIngredient11":"","strIngredient12":"","strIngredient13":"","strIngredient14":"","strIngredient15":"","strMeasure1":"1 1\/2 oz ","strMeasure2":"1\/2 oz ","strMeasure3":"1 oz ","strMeasure4":"","strMeasure5":"","strMeasure6":"","strMeasure7":"","strMeasure8":"","strMeasure9":"","strMeasure10":"","strMeasure11":"","strMeasure12":"","strMeasure13":"","strMeasure14":"","strMeasure15":"","dateModified":"2015-08-18 14:42:59"}]}

let x = drinks.drinks[0];
result = '';
for (var i=1; i<=15; i++) {
  let var1 = 'strMeasure' + i;
  let var2 = 'strIngredient' + i; 
  result = result + x[var1] + ' ' + x[var2];
}
result = result.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {"drinks":[{"idDrink":"13060","strDrink":"Margarita","strVideo":null,"strCategory":"Ordinary Drink","strIBA":"Contemporary Classics","strAlcoholic":"Alcoholic","strGlass":"Cocktail glass","strInstructions":"Rub the rim of the glass with the lime slice to make the salt stick to it. Take care to moisten only the outer rim and sprinkle the salt on it. The salt should present to the lips of the imbiber and never mix into the cocktail. Shake the other ingredients with ice, then carefully pour into the glass.","strDrinkThumb":"http:\/\/www.thecocktaildb.com\/images\/media\/drink\/wpxpvu1439905379.jpg","strIngredient1":"Tequila","strIngredient2":"Triple sec","strIngredient3":"Lime juice","strIngredient4":"Salt","strIngredient5":"","strIngredient6":"","strIngredient7":"","strIngredient8":"","strIngredient9":"","strIngredient10":"","strIngredient11":"","strIngredient12":"","strIngredient13":"","strIngredient14":"","strIngredient15":"","strMeasure1":"1 1\/2 oz ","strMeasure2":"1\/2 oz ","strMeasure3":"1 oz ","strMeasure4":"","strMeasure5":"","strMeasure6":"","strMeasure7":"","strMeasure8":"","strMeasure9":"","strMeasure10":"","strMeasure11":"","strMeasure12":"","strMeasure13":"","strMeasure14":"","strMeasure15":"","dateModified":"2015-08-18 14:42:59"}]}

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj.drinks[0]).forEach(
  function (val, idx, array) {
    document.writeln(val + ' - ' + obj.drinks[0][val]);
  }
);
```